# I have an unsigned AAB app how can I sign it to upload to the Play Store

Tags: android

I'm totally new to this, it's the first time I create an account in Play Console, the first time I use Android Studio.

I have an AAB file that would be the app that I want to upload to the Play Store, this file weighs 8mb, the problem is that when I upload it to the Play Console it tells me that it is not signed.

Searching YT I saw a tutorial on how to sign an AAB file, /Buid/Generate Signed Bundled/APK, the problem is following this tutorial the signed AAB is created but it is not the original file of my application, that is, a new one is generated that weighs 1mb.

Is there a way to take an existing unsigned AAB file and put the signature on it?

Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: This belongs to Android Enthuastics not Stack OverFlow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apksinger`. It's an command line tool that you can find it in
`AndroidSdk/BuildTools/LAST_INSTALL_VERSION_DIRECTORY/apksigner`.

Read this [article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline)